# Connecting Dialogflow to Firebase question

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have been reading around but cannot find the answer

I tried my firebase and it's not storing any data.
Here's the related inline editor

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

function angerEmotionCapture(agent) {

    let angryTo = agent.parameters.angryDirectedTo;
    agent.add(`love your ${angryTo},dude`);
    return db.collection('directedTo').add({directedTo: angryTo});
}
```

Here's my firebase database

[image: my firebase database]

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I use Firebase Realtime Database but with Python. There are few things that are missing I guess (compared to Python). 1. Link to Realtime Database, Authentication and I use the .set() or .update() for adding new entries.

Comment: this is confusing. you are saying that you are using Realtime database but your code shows something else as it seems you are using Firestore. please give more details on your use case + check your firestore panel as you may see the data there :). I guess this also would be helpful for future questions [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks @MethkalKhalawi and thanks for the link as well. I should have stored all my sources and you are right, in this sample https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/firebase-and-dialogflow-with-react-native-made-easy-part-3-5bc42793b164, they actually don't use that db.firestore, I mix-match too many sources. In the sample in URL above, I don't know how to tell my firebase URL, can you teach me how? Sorry, I'm still very early on programming.

Comment: Could you please explain what do you mean by saying "how to tell my firebase URL" ?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look into the following sample code showing how to connect Firebase's Firestore database to Dialogflow fulfillment hosting on Firebase functions:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:*'; // enables lib debugging statements
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const db = admin.firestore();

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

  function writeToDb (agent) {
    // Get parameter from Dialogflow with the string to add to the database
    const databaseEntry = agent.parameters.databaseEntry;

    // Get the database collection 'dialogflow' and document 'agent' and store
    // the document  {entry: "<value of database entry>"} in the 'agent' document
    const dialogflowAgentRef = db.collection('dialogflow').doc('agent');
    return db.runTransaction(t => {
      t.set(dialogflowAgentRef, {entry: databaseEntry});
      return Promise.resolve('Write complete');
    }).then(doc => {
      agent.add(`Wrote "${databaseEntry}" to the Firestore database.`);
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(`Error writing to Firestore: ${err}`);
      agent.add(`Failed to write "${databaseEntry}" to the Firestore database.`);
    });
  }
  
  // Map from Dialogflow intent names to functions to be run when the intent is matched
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('WriteToFirestore', writeToDb);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Have a look into the [Dialogflow's Firestore GitHub example](https://github.com/dialogflow/fulfillment-firestore-nodejs)